# by clicking on checkbox filter by specific key angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, checkbox, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this kind of Array of objects:

```
 $scope.instList= [
      {date:'06-11-2015', 25Code : '0', state: 'true', id : 21},
      {date:'15-11-2015', 25Code : '1', state: 'true', id : 22},
      {date:'24-11-2015', 25Code : '1', state: 'true', id : 23},
      {date:'28-12-2015', 25Code : '1, state: 'true', id : 24},
      {date:'28-12-2016', 25Code : '0', state: 'false', id : 241},
      {date:'28-12-2017', 25Code : '0', state: 'false',  id : 2432},
      {date:'28-11-2015', 25Code : '1', state: 'false',id : 2342},
      {date:'28-11-2017', 25Code : '0', state: 'false', id : 2443},
      {date:'28-11-2016', 25Code : '1', state: 'false', id : 2243},
      {date:'28-11-2016', 25Code : '0', state: 'false',id : 2242},


 ];
```

I have ng-repeat that displays all my data and my question is how can I create checkbox that is outside of this block with ng-repeat and its purpose to filter and display updated data which is contains only: 25Code : '1'.
example is:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="">
<ul>
  <li class="active" ng-repeat="row in instList">
  <div ng-bind="row.date"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="active" ng-repeat="row in instList">
  <div ng-bind="row.date">
  </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter to filter by a property inside your ng-repeat, for that first specify ng-true-value and ng-false value of your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterCode" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="">
```

and filter by 25code in your ng-repeat

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterCode" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="">
<ul>
  <li class="active" ng-repeat="row in instList |filter: { Code: filterCode}">
  <div ng-bind="row.date"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rTNVUwIoMXr0fDjIKGZz?p=preview)**